# vs.php remote database connection

Tags: php, sql-server-2005, apache

I'm currently using vs.php on a development client. (vs.php is a php dev IDE that uses the visual studio shell).

The problem is connecting to our remote sql 2005 database. The connectionattempt fails in less than 1 seconds. I can connect to the database with telnet without problem from the same client.

The database is set to allow remote connections.

```
$srv = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, xxxx";
$ci = array();
$ci["UID"] = "xxxxx_user";
$ci["PWD"] = "xxxxx";
$ci["DATABASE"] = "xxxx";
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($srv, $ci) OR DIE("no connection");
```

The debugger for some reason won't throw any error messages as to why the connection fails.

I just can't seem to find a solution to why it instantly drops my connection, are there any settings in the builtin vs.php webserver, or anything hardcoded in vs.php itself? Or has it anything to do with vs.php's php configuration? Are there any apache or php settings in general that could be the cause of this? Or maybe something with the database afterall?
I looked through it but couldn't find anything.

I wish I could supply more info, but I'm clueless as to why it fails.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Jonas

Comment: Audit logs on the sql server are empty so my guess is the connection is refused by the local webserver / php. Probably some vs.php nonsense but I can't confirm it. However I moved away from that solution. 

Thanks for the interest in helping though

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adjusting the case of the 'DATABASE' key in the connection options array? The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296161(SQL.90).aspx) suggests that this should be 'Database' -  might be worth a shot....

```
$srv = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, xxxx";
$ci = array();
$ci["UID"] = "xxxxx_user";
$ci["PWD"] = "xxxxx";
$ci["Database"] = "xxxx";
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($srv, $ci) OR DIE("no connection");
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply.
Yes that is correct, I've actually tried all lowercase / all uppercase and first letter capital as database key. Also tried the other keys as lowercase to with no success.

I appreciate your answer though, it's a valid point.

Comment: Yeah it seems the connection is rejected locally. But it does not matter anymore we setup a IIS with php/fastCGI and use a remote project instead. Thanks for your effort in trying to help!